# Mocking member variable of an object in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following python code to test

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__fb_access_tokens = PropertiesReader('path/to/authentication_details/file')
        self.__fb_post_write_path = PropertiesReader('path/to/write_properties/file')

    def write_information(self):
        contents = compute_file_contents()
        write_contents_to_file(self.__fb_post_write_path, contents)
```

In my testcases I want to mock the `self.__fb_post_write_path`. I cannot mock `PropertiesReader()` as it will also effect `self.__fb_access_tokens`.

Is it possible to mock member variables of an object in python?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a new value for the attribute once you've created an instance of the class. You'll have to manually 'mangle' the attribute name as you've chosen to use double-underscore names:

```
instance = Foo()
instance._Foo__fb_post_write_path = 'mocked value
```

Consider using *single* underscores instead. Unless you are writing framework classes (where a wide variety of developers will subclass your code), you want to *avoid* the name mangling feature.

If you *must* intercept the call to `PropertiesReader`, then mock `PropertiesReader` anyway, but pass through a call to the original unpatched object for certain attributes. Set `Mock.side_effect` to a function and vary behaviour based on the arguments:

```
from module import PropertiesReader  # so you have access to the unpatched version

with mock.patch('module_under_test.PropertiesReader') as propreader_mock:
    def pr_side_effect(path):
        if path == 'path/to/authentication_details/file':
            return PropertiesReader(path)
        return mock.DEFAULT
    propreader_mock.side_effect = pr_side_effect
```

Returning `mock.DEFAULT` tells the mock to fall back to the default behaviour (e.g. produce another `Mock` instance or produce the `return_value` you set).